# How do I plot very big dat file in gnuplot?

Tags: gnuplot

I have a **.dat** file with **50000 rows** and **101 columns** and try to plot in **GNUPLOT** by using command **plot "test.dat" matrix with image" **. But no plot occurs . PLz help.

Comment: 1. Test with a 100 line subset of your file. 2. Run `gnuplot`, type `help`, and follow your nose to `help plot`.

Comment: this problem not happens for 35,000 . but while I give more rows then the problem starts. @ waltinator

Answer (score 0):

Probably too late, but just wanted to put the solution out there:

```
set terminal postscript size 12, 10 enhanced color
set output 'worked.eps'
plot 'file_with_57k_rows_and_400_columns.tsv' matrix with image
```

Apparently `postrscript` terminal works but `eps` or `png` don't. This will result in big eps file size, but `ps2pdf` may be handy later.